# spring jpa @Query error, expecting CLOSE, found '(' near

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have following JPQL:

```
@Query("SELECT su.id, su.nameCn, count(b.id), avg(s.rate), count(concat(b.id, '@', s.user.id)) "
            + "FROM S su, B b, S s where b.st.id = su.id and s.bd.id = b.id and su.mt.id = ?1 group by su.id")
```

When I add `concat(b.id, '@', s.user.id)`, it shows me:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1,
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]

Comment: It appears you are not allowed to nest function calls inside `count()`.

Answer (score 20):

> expecting CLOSE, found `(`

The term CLOSE here refers to a closing bracket, `)`.

It would appear that the query parser does not support calling another function inside the `count(...)`.

In other words, the syntax error is here:

```
SELECT su.id, su.nameCn, count(b.id), avg(s.rate), count(concat(b.id, '@', s.user.id))
                                                               ^
```

Perhaps you mean to be doing some kind of join, and counting the rows there?

Comment: yes, what I want exactly is count(concat(b.id, '@', s.user.id)). if I can't write like this, is there any way to instead of this format

Comment: What you want doesn't make any sense. The concat function doesn't change the number of rows.

Comment: if I only count b.id, it give me 4 records, if I count(concat(b.id, '@', s.user.id)), this actually makes b.id and s.user.id as unique key, I will get 2 records, narrowed search results

Comment: You need to write a proper join/where query and count the rows of that.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is using both count and concatenate function together.

If you write your query without count() like below, should work. 
This is just for testing to know who is causing the issue exactly.

Try writing query different way using count and concatenate seperatly.

```
...concat(b.id, '@', s.user.id)....
```

Comment: yes, I have test if only add count(b.id), it works. but actually I want count(concat(b.id, '@', s.user.id)), when I add concat, it shows me error. so do you know how to write format like this count(concat(b.id, '@', s.user.id)) in spring data