# Spring JPA query alternative to CAST(x as DECIMAL(y,z))

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have this Spring JPA mySQL query

```
@Query("SELECT centro FROM 
 Centro centro WHERE CAST(y_geo as DECIMAL(20,10)) < :y_geo + 0.1 
 AND CAST(y_geo as DECIMAL(20,10)) > :y_geo - 0.1 
 AND CAST(x_geo as DECIMAL(20,10)) < :x_geo + 0.1 
 AND CAST(x_geo as DECIMAL(20,10)) > :x_geo - 0.1")
```

And returns this error

```
MismatchedTokenException: expecting CLOSE, found '('
```

I understand that it's not possible to nest 2 functions on JPA like here

[spring jpa @Query error, expecting CLOSE, found '(' near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475872/spring-jpa-query-error-expecting-close-found-near)

What it's the alternative to my query? 
Thanks!

Comment: I recently ran into a similar problem and found that `CONVERT(y_geo, DECIMAL)` worked. Try that (or `CONVERT(y_geo, DECIMAL(20, 10))`).

Comment: Still not working, same error. Thanks

Comment: Which of the two options did you try and what version of Spring Data JPA are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I have let "as"...

CONVERT(y_geo, DECIMAL) -> Works, but no parses decimals, only integer

CONVERT(y_geo, DECIMAL(20, 10)) -> Works, launch another error that I have to fix. 

Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed, CONVERT(x, DECIMAL(y,z)) Works!