# Problem with custom Query in Spring boot JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to count the number of record by ranges, but I'm gettin an error when I run the service:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '<' near line 1, column 58 [SELECT new net.BBB.ProjectB.entity.AgeCount(COUNT(s.edad < 15 OR NULL), COUNT(s.edad < 25 AND s.edad > 16 OR NULL), COUNT(s.edad < 35 AND s.edad > 26 OR NULL), COUNT(s.edad < 45 AND s.edad > 36 OR NULL), COUNT(s.edad > 46 OR NULL),FROM net.BBB.ProjectB.entity.Student AS s) ]
```

When I execute the Query in the database, it works perfectly. The code of my repository is

```
package net.BBB.ProjectB.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import net.BBB.ProjectB.entity.AgeCount;
import net.BBB.ProjectB.entity.NacionalityCount;
import net.BBB.ProjectB.entity.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

    List<Student> findByNombre(String nombre);

    @Query(value = "SELECT new net.BBB.ProjectB.entity.NacionalityCount(COUNT(s.nacionalidad), s.nacionalidad) "
            + "FROM Student AS s GROUP BY s.nacionalidad")
    List<NacionalityCount> countByNacionalidad();

    @Query(value = "SELECT new net.BBB.ProjectB.entity.AgeCount(COUNT(s.edad < 15 OR NULL), "
            + "COUNT(s.edad < 25 AND s.edad > 16 OR NULL), COUNT(s.edad < 35 AND s.edad > 26 OR NULL), "
            + "COUNT(s.edad < 45 AND s.edad > 36 OR NULL), COUNT(s.edad > 46 OR NULL),"
            + "FROM Student AS s) ")
    List<AgeCount> countByAge();

}
```

The first query works fine, the second one is the problem. Just in case, the name of the entity is Student and it has a attribute called "edad" that I'm trying to count by ranges. I have tried with other queries that work on the database, like:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.edad BETWEEN 0 AND 16 OR NULL), 
        COUNT(s.edad BETWEEN 17 AND 25 OR NULL), 
        COUNT(s.edad BETWEEN 26 AND 35 OR NULL),
        COUNT(s.edad BETWEEN 35 AND 45 OR NULL)
FROM students AS s;
```

Obviously with the name of the entity. I have no idea if there is a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but in your HQL query you have a "," at the end plus a ")", which should be somewhere else?

```
  + "COUNT(s.edad < 45 AND s.edad > 36 OR NULL), COUNT(s.edad > 46 OR NULL),"
            + "FROM Student AS s) ")
```

In general, I would try to fix this query step by step. I.e. replace all counts with a static number, then replace 1 count with the real expression, once that works, replace the next one etc.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice about that, already corrected them, but the error persists. I found a similar question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475872/spring-jpa-query-error-expecting-close-found-near) and as it says "It would appear that the query parser does not support calling another function inside the count(...)", so I have no idea how to write this query.