# Comparing a BigDecimal with a precision 2 with the data that has 3 precision using CAST or CONVERT in JPA query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot, jpa

I have a field numeric and I'm showing the data using a precision that the user specifies.

If I have 1.246 in the database and the users precision is 2, I will show them 1.25

For now everything is good, the problem is in the UI there is a filter that uses a JPA query, is there a way that when the user sends 1.25 I will return that element since the value scaled is actually 1.25.

I was wondering if there is anything like:

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM T WHERE amount BETWEEN CAST(:amount AS NUMBER(19,2))")
List<Long> findXYZ(@Param("amount") BigDecimal);
```

I use convert or cast but I still get [spring jpa @Query error, expecting CLOSE, found '(' near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475872/spring-jpa-query-error-expecting-close-found-near).

I prefer not using native queries because I have many entities and don't want to do any joins manually.

Comment: don't bind query to ui!

Comment: the data is passed to a controller->service->dao it's not drectly binded