# How to count distinct years in Date Spring Query DSL?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, querydsl

when I count distinct years in date by this query

```
List count = queryFactory.select(qTestEntity.createdDate.year().countDistinct()).from(qTestEntity)
                .fetch();
```

It gives me an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1, column 27 [select count(distinct year(testEntity.createdDate))
from  testEntity]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor184.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:101) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:94) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.fetch(AbstractJPAQuery.java:201)
```

After investigation, I found a question about that:-
[spring JPA @Query error, expecting CLOSE, found '(' near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475872/spring-jpa-query-error-expecting-close-found-near)

Does there is any workaround to get distinct years without native query?

Answer (score 1):

Not all date extract functions are supported in Hibernate, because no function for it exists in Hibernate out of the box. Also Hibernate doesn't seem to support a COUNT distinct operation over a function or parameterized expression.

You could consider the [Blaze-Persistence Querydsl integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#querydsl-integration) which provides more advanced aggregate and date extract functions to Hibernate.

Comment: Thanx  @Jan-Willem Gmelig Meyling.
Can we do that with GroupBy?
Please if we can give me a pseudo query.